# React Native: require('NativeModules') How to import my own native library properly?

Tags: ios, react-native

I built a new native iOS library for ReactNative. In my project i did "react-native new-library --name FetchBinary" to create the library with all boilerplate code.

I exported the method like this:

```
@implementation FetchBinary

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

// Fetch blob data request
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(fetchBinary:(NSString *)taskId method:(NSString *)method url:(NSString *)url headers:(NSDictionary *)headers body:(NSString *)body callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
   // ... lot of code ...            
}
```

I added the XcodeProject-file to my libraries-folder:

[image]

But i can't import this native module properly.

I tried both:

```
const NativeFetchBinary = require('NativeModules').FetchBinary;
const FetchBinary = NativeModules.FetchBinary
```

Both variables are "undefined".

If i do "console.log(NativeModules)" i get a list of many native modules but not my module.

Comment: Is your libFetchBinary.a properly linked to the final app?

Comment: This happened to me for the SQLite storage module. It has these lines, but it doesn't become available on the JS side